# Assets pipeline with Rails and Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, asset-pipeline

I can not solve problem with production environment. My application.css on heroku is empty, while in development it's wokrks fine.

In my application.rb I added this:
`config.assets.enabled = true`
`config.assets.compress = false`
but it still doesn't work.

Precompiling is not working too. After I made it, heroku puts a message that it have found a manifest file, but still - is not working. To rollback it i used rake assets:clean. The message still appears.

What can I do? I have only one CSS file with no JS.

Link to app:
http://floating-hamlet-8270.herokuapp.com/

Part of my Application.css:

```
/*
* This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.css, which will include all      the files
* listed below.
*
* Any CSS and SCSS file within this directory, lib/assets/stylesheets, vendor/assets/stylesheets,
* or vendor/assets/stylesheets of plugins, if any, can be referenced here using a relative path.
*
* You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at the top of the
* compiled file, but it's generally better to create a new file per style scope.
*
*= require_self
*= require_tree .
*/

html, body, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, ul, li {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

body {
 font-family: "Noto Sans", sans-serif;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the following from [Heroku's documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-asset-pipeline):

> If a public/assets/manifest.yml is detected in your app, Heroku will
>   assume you are handling asset compilation yourself and will not
>   attempt to compile your assets.

You must either delete your `manifest.yml` file to let Heroku manage your assets or properly configure it.

Comment: In both situations pushing to Heroku goes right, but files is not GETed by browser. Unfortunatelly, I tried everything in documentation but styles still not appears... Is there are a way to disable sprockets in Heroku?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following...

Add to gemfile:

gem 'rails_12factor', group: :production

Add to /config/production.rb:

config.serve_static_assets = true

config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Accel-Redirect'

config.assets.compile = true

See https://medium.com/self-directed-learning/9ba1f595102a